# Error property does not exist in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, properties, undefined

I have a number type initialized at the beginning of my component class like this:
My component class:

```html
import { .....


@Component({
   ....
})
export class JhiLoginModalComponent implements  OnInit {
   
    a: number;
 

   
    ngOnInit() {
      this.method();

    }
    method() {
     a=3;
    }
```

My testing class:

```html
import {...

  describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  
    let comp: ComponentClass;
        let fixture: ComponentFixture<ComponentClass>;
          beforeEach(async(() => {
            TestBed.configureTestingModule({
              ............
        }));
        
          beforeEach(() => {
            fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponnetClass);
            comp = fixture.componentInstance;
            ....
              });
              //MY TEST
                it ('Should print a value', async(() => {
fixture.detectChanges();
            console.log('lalalalla' + comp.method.a); //It prints lalalaundefined
            
        }));
```

It returns undefined when I print domElement and the error: Property **a** is undefined for type any

Do I make an error in injection?? How can I access the component elements otherwise?? If I use this number later it says that it is undefined.

Comment: Why do you have an async beforeEach and a regular one? what is inside of them? you misspelled ComponnetClass, but I assume in your actual code it's correct?

Comment: Yeah because my code is too long, so I am simplifying it for you. Inside beforeEach and async are the imports and the inicialization of teh testing environment that makes angular by default :)

Comment: Does the property .method.a exist on ComponentClass? If a is a variable inside a function, it exists only as long as the function is being processed.

Answer (score 1):

`ngOnInit` is not called when the component is created. It is the Angular engine which calls it, when the component is ready to be used (the inputs are set, including data-bound properties). Add a `console.log` to `ngOnInit` an you'll see it has not been called before the `console.log` in your test. You need to call `fixture.detectChanges()` first.

EDITED (based on your comment):

I just realised. You're logging `comp.method.a`, but `comp.method` is a function, so it does not have an `a` property. You should log `comp.a`:

```
console.log('lalala' + comp.a);
```

Comment: Yeah Im sorry I didnt put it there. I have a fixture.DetectChanges inside the test method

Comment: Edited. I think I realised what the problem is

Comment: It doesnt give teh error that the property is undefined, but prints lalalundefined. I want to print lalalala3